# rviz/gazebo path plot

Tags: gazebo, rviz, path, plot, p3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
I'd like to plot the path followed by my robot (a p3dx) during the simulation.
 Is it possible to do it in gazebo or with a rviz plugin?
Any suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51601/rviz/gazebo-path-plot/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [hector_trajectory_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_trajectory_server) node does what you request. It publishes the path traveled as a nav_msgs/Path which can easily be visualized in rviz (but not gazebo). See also [this Q/A very similar to yours](http://answers.ros.org/question/28069/how-to-visualize-a-frame-pose-as-a-path/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2